# How to return value of optional after mapping in java 8

Tags: java, string, lambda, java-8, option-type

I need to get the String value which is the identifier, but this return void instead of string value.
How can I return the string value?

```
    String previousReadyForHome = information.getPreviousContact().ifPresent(val->{
      Arrays.stream(val.basic.identifiers).filter(s -> s.type == readyForHomeType)
        .map(s -> s.identifier).findFirst().orElse(null);
    });
```

Comment: Dont do `ifPresent`. but `.map` or `.flatMap` on the given `Optional`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use `ifPresent`, as you have found out, it returns `void`. Rather, you should use `flatMap`, which gives you another `Optional<String>`, which you can then use `orElse` to unwrap it to `null`.

```
String previousReadyForHome = information.getPreviousContact().flatMap(val->
  Arrays.stream(val.basic.identifiers).filter(s -> s.type == readyForHomeType)
    .map(s -> s.identifier).findFirst()
).orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your classes names:

```java
Optional<String> previousReadyForHome = information.getPreviousContact()
    .map(Contact::getBasic)
    .map(BasicInfo::getIdentifiers)
    .flatMap(identifiers -> Arrays.stream(identifiers)
        .filter(identifier -> identifier.getType() == readyForHomeType)
        .map(Identifier::getIdentifier)
        .findFirst());
```

It is just a more readable approach.